# How can I avoid NaN and add & substract on OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

*I have a initial value of 10000 and I want to add or substract the initial value depending to the value I input. For example, I click the radio button name Add I want to disable the 2nd textBox. Enter a value into 1st textbox. Add the initial value and the value of textbox1. When I click the 2nd radio button name Minus I want to disable the 1st textBox minus 2nd textbox to initial value. OOP style. When I click the compute button it show the answer and back it to normal so I can choose and enter another number add it to table.*

```js
//external script
function Compute(initialNum, numOne, numTwo) {
 this._initialNum = initialNum; // 10000
 this._numOne = numOne; //input by user
 this._numTwo = numTwo; //input by user

 this.addNum = function() {
     
     this._initialNum = this._initialNum + this._numOne;
     return this._initialNum;
   };
 this.minusNum = function() {
     
     this._initialNum = this._initialNum - this._numTwo;
     return this._initialNum;
   };
}
 //JavaScript in <body>
 var initialValue = 10000;
 var numOne = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumOne'));
 var numTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById('txtNumTwo'));
 var rdoAdd = document.getElementById("rdoAdd").value;
    var rdoMinus = document.getElementById("rdoMinus").value;
 var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");

 function disableTxtAdd() {
       if(rdoAdd == "rdoAdd") {
            document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled = true;
       }
       else{
         document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled = false;
       }
   }
    function disableTxtMinus() {
       if(rdoMinus == "rdoMinus") {
            document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled = true;
       }
       else{
         document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled = false;
       }
   }
 function print() {
  var objAccount = new Compute(initialValue, numOne.value, numTwo.value);
  var display = "";

  if(rdoAdd.checked)
  {
   display += "<tr>";
   display += "<td>" + objAccount.addNum() + "</td>";
   display += "<tr>";
   tblResult.innerHTML = display;

  } else {
   display += "<tr>";
   display += "<td>" + objAccount.minusNum() + "</td>";
   display += "<tr>";
   tblResult.innerHTML = display;
  }
 }
```

```html
<input name = "operation" type = "radio" id = "rdoAdd" value = "rdoAdd" onclick = "disableTxtAdd()">Add<br><br>
 <input name = "operation" type = "radio" id = "rdoMinus" value = "rdoMinus" onclick = "disableTxtMinus()">Minus<br><br>
 Deposit:<br><br>
 <input type = "text" id = "txtNumOne"><br><br>
 Withdraw<br><br>
 <input type = "text" id = "txtNumTwo">
 <button onclick = "print()">Compute</button><br><br>

 <table border = "1px">
  <th>Result</th>

  <tbody id = "tblResult">
   
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Angelica's calculator</title>

 <script>
 // When the Add button is clicked
 function disableTxtAdd() {

        document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled = false;

 }

 // When the Minus button is clicked   
 function disableTxtMinus() {

        document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled = false;

 }

 // When the Compute button is clicked
 function print(){

     var initialValue = 10000;
     var numOne = document.getElementById('txtNumOne').value;
     var numTwo = document.getElementById('txtNumTwo').value;   

     var tblResult = document.getElementById("tblResult");  

     var display;
     var result;


    if(document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled){

     // Add input value to 10000
         if(Number.isInteger(parseInt(numOne))){

             result = initialValue + parseInt(numOne);

         }else{

             result = "Enter a number";

         }

        display = "<tr><td>" + result + "</td><tr>";

        tblResult.innerHTML = display;

         }else if(document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled){

             // Subtract input from 10000
             if(Number.isInteger(parseInt(numTwo))){

                 result = initialValue - parseInt(numTwo);

             }else{

                 result = "Enter a number";

             }

        display = "<tr><td>" + result + "</td><tr>";

        tblResult.innerHTML = display;
     }

     // Enable both inputs
     document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").disabled = false;
     document.getElementById("txtNumOne").disabled = false; 

     // Empty the inputs
     document.getElementById("txtNumTwo").value = "";
     document.getElementById("txtNumOne").value = "";           

 }
 </script>  

 </head>
 <body>

 <input name="operation" type="radio" id="rdoAdd" value="rdoAdd" onclick="disableTxtAdd()">Add<br><br>
 <input name="operation" type="radio" id="rdoMinus" value="rdoMinus" onclick="disableTxtMinus()">Minus<br><br>

 Deposit:<br />
 <input type="text" id="txtNumOne"><br /><br />

 Withdraw<br />
 <input type="text" id="txtNumTwo"><br /><br />

 <button onclick="print()">Compute</button><br /><br />

 <table border="1px" style="border-collapse:collapse";>
    <th>Result</th>

    <tbody id = "tblResult">

    </tbody>
 </table>


 </body>
 </html>
```